# Apache does not listen on port 42

Tags: apache

I try to make Apache listen on port 42 instead of the default port.

I modified `ports.conf` :

```
Listen 42
<IfModule ssl_module>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

And also the vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:42>

    ServerName nano

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

but when I try to access "localhost:42/", nothing happens.

/var/log/apache2/error.log contains 2 lines :

```
[Wed Jul 02 15:50:04.572479 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1690] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 02 15:50:04.572514 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1690] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

In top, I can see

```
/usr/bin/apache2 -k start
```

But command `fuser -n tcp 42` does not show anything. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port 42 is open on your firewall.

If IP Tables

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 42 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Did not work. But replacing 42 with 8081 did the work. So it is probably still a problem of permissions with ports.